# Display Wireless Temperature Sensor data to Web page by using Serial communication

Tags: serial, web-server, wireless

I am reading from [wireless temperature sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/industrial-long-range-wireless-temperature-humidity-sensor/) with help of gateway receiver connected to Arduino UNO, using this [code](https://github.com/bhaskar-anil429/Long-Range-wireless-temperature-Humidity-sensor-Arduino/blob/master/Long_Range_Wireless_Temperature_Humidity_Sensor_Arduino.ino)

I need to display the data of the wireless sensor on the webpage. 
Any suggestion on which help to start working using serial com or should I have to use Ethernet port for this?

Comment: On *what* web page?

Answer (score -1):

So you want to read serial port data from a webpage, I am not a web developer, but I suggest you to read the following links.
You can use a local server to read the data (NodeJs, php) :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549151/how-to-read-serial-port-data-from-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619929/read-data-form-serial-port-on-windows-with-php